# Why i am getting this error (HTTP error 400.) when I send to many request?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

Request 61E31B28-2196-41FC-9F82-B60D236D4347 failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
I am getting this error when i send multiple request to fetch data from twitter

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your application reached her rate limit, take a look [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting)

Answer (score 0):

its a server response status **HTTP CODE = 400** means there could be any error or mistake in parameters of your URL so it gives **response 400 as bad request**.

And when it give **HTTP CODE = 200** means all is well and it gives as **success**.

Comment: Request 4A6E3E81-C81F-4187-B768-F76606102D7E failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"